# imapclient is working fine when I run it by hand but not when I run it using cron

Tags: pi-3b+, cron, python-2.x

Currently, I have a python program where my pi will check if a certain email address has a certain email and then run another piece of code. When I run the script normally there is no issue with it, but when I use cron to run the code imapclient seems to fail to log in. I have the cron logging to a file and is printing the error message ERROR which is the only message with that name in my code. The file does state that the script is attempting to log in. Here is part of my code,

```
!/usr/bin/env python

from imapclient import IMAPClient, SEEN

SEEN_FLAG = 'SEEN'
UNSEEN_FLAG = 'UNSEEN'

class GmailWrapper:
   def __init__(self, host, userName, password):
       #   force the user to pass along username and password to log in as 
       self.host = host
       self.userName = userName
       self.password = password
       self.login()

   def login(self):
       try:
           print('Logging in as ' + self.userName)
           server = IMAPClient(self.host, use_uid=True, ssl=True)
           server.login(self.userName, self.password)
           self.server = server
       except:
           print("Error")
           pass
```

I have the cron set up to run and at boot and it does say that it is attempting to log in but then throws me with the error message. "Error" which means that imapclient has failed to log in.  The code I'm using to run the imap client is the following.

```
gmailWrapper = GmailWrapper(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD)

def checkByGmail():
    ids = gmailWrapper.getIdsBySubject('check bus')
    email = False
    if(len(ids) > 0):
        try:
            gmailWrapper.markAsRead(ids)
            email = True
        except:
            print("Failed to Mark as read")
            pass
    return email
```

Hostname is set as imap.gmail.com. I will not be saying Username and password for obvious reasons. This is not the full code just the information I deem relevant. Any ideas why it's not logging into imap?

Comment: *which means that imapclient has failed to log in* Actually it means any error has occurred - I would start by adding a bit of debugging code to find the actual error and make sure you are running this as pi and not root (or have the correct security access for root), have same paths for cron job as interactive, starting from the same folder - one of those three normally catch me once a month :(

Comment: You tell us that your script runs *manually*, but not from `cron`. Then, you give us the code that's **working**, but not the call from your `crontab`. Do you see anything wrong with your question?

Comment: you say that you get `the error message. "ERROR"` but your code prints `Error` ... are you sure your code is producing the error?